# Makefile:13: *** missing separator. Stop. error in bsdiff-4.3

Tags: makefile, ubuntu-14.04

please help me to compile the following Makefile.

```
CFLAGS      +=  -O3 -lbz2

PREFIX      ?=  /usr/local
INSTALL_PROGRAM ?=  ${INSTALL} -c -s -m 555
INSTALL_MAN ?=  ${INSTALL} -c -m 444

all:        bsdiff bspatch
bsdiff:     bsdiff.c
bspatch:    bspatch.c

install:
    ${INSTALL_PROGRAM} bsdiff bspatch ${PREFIX}/bin
.ifndef WITHOUT_MAN
    ${INSTALL_MAN} bsdiff.1 bspatch.1 ${PREFIX}/man/man1
.endif
```

while i am trying make the file it shows an error

```
Makefile:13: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

i am using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Unless you are making changes of your own, you should not need to compile this utility yourself.  And if you do need to recompile it with changes of your own, it probably makes sense to download the Debian (and thus Ubuntu) source package and make changes to that instead. See http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=bsdiff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ifndef` is not valid GNU Make syntax.  You need to remove the full stop you have in front of `ifndef` and `endif`.

See also the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Syntax.html).